# Flask send email when user comes across an error WITH all request values (POST/GET)

Tags: python, flask

Standard code within the Flask frameworks allows people to be emailed when a user comes across a page that causes an error, typically (and what I've implemented) looks like this in the `app.py` script:

```
from app import app
...
if not app.debug:
    import logging
    from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler
    mail_handler = SMTPHandler(EMAIL_SERVER,
                               EMAIL_FROM,
                               EMAIL_ADMINS, 
                               EMAIL_SUBJECT,
                               credentials=(EMAIL_ EMAIL,'***'),
                               port=EMAIL_PORT)
    mail_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    app.logger.addHandler(mail_handler)
```

This is great as it sends an email containing information to start the debugging process looking like:

```
Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "hello.py", line 6, in hello_world
raise Exception
Exception
```

What this doesn't contain the is the GET/POST variables that users are entering.  These can be key to the debugging process and that is my question.  How can you have all `request.form` variables (for GET/POST) included in this email?

While I could not find a direct answer to the question via Google, the closest resource I've found is the Flask docs (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/logging/#logging) which has a section on **"Injecting Request Information"** which talks about subclassing `logging.Formatter` but it refers to extra information such as IP addresses and requires identifying specific values.

Which brings me to my question:

How can one modify the logging email to include the error AND all request (GET/POST) data from the users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two weeks later and still no definitely answer to my question.  A work around I've found is to modifiy the 500 error handler:

```
@app.errorhandler(500)
def status_code_500(exc):
    # do stuff in here
```

From here the solution would be to dump all `request.args` and `request.form` values into a string using `json.dumps(request.args, indent=4, sort_keys=True)`. That can be turned into an email and we can use this `@app.errorhandler` to send off an email via SMTPhandler preferably on a new thread so the user isn't blocked.

We can also include the stack traceback in this email with `traceback.formatexc`.

It's a bit of work around as we are basically re-writing the already built in existing code but I have yet to find a solution that allows us to add text into the email of the logging.handler.